# Commutative diagram for Hopf Algebra

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, commutative-diagrams

I'd like to reproduce the following diagram:

[image]

I've seen there are code for similar exagons on this website but I'm not that good with tikz to generalise them and add the central line..

Thank you!

Comment: What are you try? Publish a [_Minimal Working Example_](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: Questions of the form "Please draw this for me", which show no effort on the part of OP, often don't get answered. You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). You can place the vertices of your hexagon using polar coordinates, `(0:1)`, `(60:1)`, ...,`(300:1)`, and then draw the arrows.  If you at least make a start you are more likely to get help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\id}{\mathrm{id}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3.6em,column sep=1em]
& H\otimes H \arrow[rr,"S\otimes\id"] && H\otimes H \arrow[dr,"\nabla"] \\
H \arrow[ur,"\Delta"] \arrow[rr,"\varepsilon"] \arrow[dr,"\Delta"'] && K \arrow[rr,"\eta"] && H \\
& H\otimes H \arrow[rr,"\id\otimes S"'] && H\otimes H \arrow[ur,"\nabla"']
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]